# Freeze first tab in C#.net tab control

Tags: c#, .net, tabs, freeze

Is there a way to freeze the first tab of a C#.net tab control?

I have a tab controller which can have many tabs. If the user is scrolling them the first tab should remain in the first position and rest of the tabs should move.

I have tried to do it using removing and inserting the tab in paint method. But seems like it is getting index issues some times when I tried to remove and add the first page.

```
            // For the first time home tab comes as the first tab item
            if (this.homeTab == null)
            {
                this.homeTab = this.TabPages[0];
            }

            // get initial first display index to a temp variable
            int tempFirstIndex = -1;
            for (int index = 0; index < this.TabCount; index++)
            {
                Rectangle currentTabBounds = this.GetTabTextRect(index);

                if (currentTabBounds != Rectangle.Empty && tempFirstIndex < 0 && currentTabBounds.X >= 0)
                {
                    tempFirstIndex = index;
                    break;

                }
            }

            int homeTabIndex = this.TabPages.IndexOf(this.homeTab);
            Rectangle homeTabBounds = this.GetTabTextRect(homeTabIndex);

            if (homeTabIndex > tempFirstIndex)
            {
                this.TabPages.Remove(this.homeTab);
                this.TabPages.Insert(tempFirstIndex, this.homeTab);
            }
            else
            {
                // find the first visible position
                // it can not be simply the tempFirstIndex, because in this scenario tab is removed from begining
                // tabs are not same in width
                while (homeTabBounds != Rectangle.Empty && homeTabBounds.X < 0)
                {
                    homeTabIndex++;
                    this.TabPages.Remove(this.homeTab);
                    this.TabPages.Insert(homeTabIndex, this.homeTab);
                    homeTabBounds = this.GetTabTextRect(homeTabIndex);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think you need to better explain your issue. The first tab page will always remain the first page irrespective of which page your on.

Comment: First tab hides if you have more tabs than it can show in the display area. Then you should use scroll control to navigate to the first page. Hope I have explained the question. Basically I need to freeze the first tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to freeze the first tab.

The problem with the above solution is, I tried to manipulate the tab page list inside the paint method. It causes to call the paint method over and over again and generates exceptions.

So I have tried to manipulate the tab position returned from "this.GetTabTextRect(index)". It worked fine. But I had to write some code to adjust the tab selection logic as well.

protected Rectangle GetTabTextRect(int index)
{

```
// gets the original tab position
Rectangle tabBounds = this.GetTabRect(index);

// first displayed index will be calculated in the paint method
// if it is equal or less than to zero means, the number of tabs are not exceeded the display limit. So no need tab manipulating
if (this.firstDisplayedIndex > 0 )
{
    // if it is not first tab we adjust the position
    if (index > 0)
    {
        if (index > this.firstDisplayedIndex && index <= this.lastDisplayedIndex)
        {
            Rectangle prevBounds = this.CurrentTabControl.GetTabRect(this.firstDisplayedIndex);

            // home tab (first tab) bounds will be stored in a global variable when the tab control initializes
            tabBounds.X = tabBounds.X - prevBounds.Width + this.homeTabBounds.Width;
        }
        else if (index == this.firstDisplayedIndex) // we need to free this slot for the first tab (index = 0)
        {
            tabBounds.X -= 1000;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // first tab position is fixed
        tabBounds.X = 0;
    }
}
```

}